# Notepad++ Remove all except text inside brackets

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of Russian surnames, with some other stuff in the way. I want to remove everything except the English version of the surname, which is inside the brackets.

I have ...

```
 1   Иванов (Ivanov)     5,043,000
 2   Смирнов (Smirnov)   3,419,000
 3   Васильев (Vasilev)  2,464,000
```

And want...

```
Ivanov
Smirnov
Vasilev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have it in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)\((.+)\)(.+)`
- Replace with: `\2`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Notepad++ supports [Regular Expressions](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) this should do the trick nicely